# Is there a generic way to make a "View" over an existing list allowing changes that only stick after a commit method is called?

Tags: c#

Hi I have a use case where I would like to have a warper around a list (could be array or span) that allows would act like another list. The point is that it will only act like a single list but wont commit any changes untill merge is called.

```
Example

var orgList = List<int>{1,2,3}

orgList  => viewList<int>(orgList);

viewList.Remove(viewList.Last());
viewList.Add(4);

orgList -> 1, 2, 3

viewList -> 1, 2, 4

viewList.Merge()

orgList -> 1, 2, 4

viewList -> 1, 2, 4
```

I am able to make this work but id like to avoid using my custom class that handles this with custom methods pointing out (push, pop, getbyindex, merge) that more or less give me the bare min i need.

Is there a more generic way of doing this? I feel like I am reinventing the wheel. In the past I just made a full copy of my first list, did what i wanted and if i liked the result i would copy the results into my init list, but that proved to be way to expensive.

Comment: You could make things hard and use the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to view and merge the changes, or, if you're not concerned about the extra memory, you could just track a separate list that you make the changes to and then `Merge()` changes the primary list member to reference the changed list.

Comment: I am doing the one at the moment. And its fine, but the fact I have to be able to be able to remove items just makes it a bit tricky. I have feeling ill need to stick with that. I dont mind using some etc memory. I just cant afford to copy and paste the entire list again and again. so the list is semi large and happens 10-100 times and its for a game that I want to be repsonsive. But thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The Syatem.Collections.Immutable types have builders that would help with this.